# PHP pagination error with only 1 page

Tags: php, pagination

I have a problem with pagination, i see only first page, i try to undestand. I have  a file HTML with a script and the script launch a file php. But the result is only a file

```
<?php 
    include 'database.php';
    $output = ''; 
    $start=0;
    $limit=2;

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $start=($id-1)*$limit;
    }else{
        $id=1;
    }

    $search = $_POST["search"];
    if($search == ''){
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM dati ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
    }
    else {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM dati WHERE nome LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
    }

    $retval = mysqli_query( $dbconfig, $sql);
    $output .= '
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Numero di Telefono</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($retval)){
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                <td>'. $row['nome'] . '</td>
                <td>'. $row['categoria'] . '</td>
                <td>'. $row['telefono'] . '</td>
                </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '
            </tbody>
            </table>';
    $ret = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query( $dbconfig, $sql));
    $total=ceil($ret/$limit);
    $output .= '
    <div class="row">
    <ul class="page">';
    for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++){
        if($i==$id) { 
            $output .= '<li class="corrente">'.$i.'</li>'; 
        }else { 
            $output .= '<li><a href=?id='.$i.'>'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }
    $output .= '
    </ul>
    </div>';

    echo $output;
?>
```

This is file PHP with pagination but nothing

```html
<input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="Ricerca">
```

Comment: is $_GET['id'] set? Are you sure you're using get and not post?

Comment: *I have a file HTML with a script and the script launch a file php. But the result is only a file*, what do you mean by this? Also, clearly state your problem, what is not working?

Comment: I'm not expert of php, i copy code php and i edit with for my site. $_GET['id']  is only on page ricerca.php. The problem is ricerca.php can output two pages or three but for now i only see one page

Comment: @Luca You mean to say, when you search for something, it only displays one page, whereas it's supposed to display 3 pagination links as well at the bottom of the page, is this correct? Or is it like even though you don't search for anything, still it displays only one page and no(or may be one) pagination links at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, is correct. The problem is if(isset($_GET['id']) i try with POST but is the same. What i can do?

Comment: I try to resolve the problem. There are a problem with mysqli_num_rows. Now i see the pagination but when i click on page nothing of result change what i can do?